# React Native WebView Error: Undefined is not a Function

Tags: webview, expo

I have an expo manged react native app and I am using react Native WebView to integrate paypal payment into my app.But everytime the webstateUrl of the webview changes i get an error: ERROR  TypeError: undefined is not a function, js engine: hermes.If i refresh the component the error goes away and I am at the screen or the url where I need to be and everything works fine as it should until the url changes again and I get the error again.

I thought that the error is coming because there is something wrong with the onNavigationStateChange prop of the webView so i tired removing it and rerunning my app bu i still get the error. this is my code:

```
import { View, Text, Alert, Modal } from "react-native";
import React, { useContext, useState } from "react";
import { Wrapper } from "../../../infrastructure/components/Wrapper";
import ImageHeader from "../../../infrastructure/components/ImageHeader";
import TicketFinderHeader from "../TicketFinder/TicketFinderComponents/Header/TicketFinderHeader";
import { T } from "../../../infrastructure/components/Text";
import PaymentDetailsCard from "./PaymentDetailsCard/PaymentDetailsCard";
import { ApiResponseContext } from "../../../services/context/ApiResponseContext/ApiResponseContextProvider";
import { Button } from "react-native-paper";
import {
  captureOrder,
  createOrder,
  generateToken,
} from "../../../services/context/Paypal/paypal";
import { WebView } from "react-native-webview";
import queryString from "query-string";

export default function Paypal({ navigation }) {
  const { selectedtotal } = useContext(ApiResponseContext);
  const [accessToken, setAccessToken] = useState();
  const [paypalUrl, setPaypalUrl] = useState();

  const handlePress = async () => {
    try {
      const token = await generateToken();
      const res = await createOrder(token);
      setAccessToken(token);
      console.log("res is ", res);
      if (!!res?.links) {
        const findUrl = res.links.find((data) => data?.rel === "approve");
        console.log(findUrl);
        setPaypalUrl(findUrl?.href);
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
    // Alert.alert(
    //   "Payment Declined",
    //   `You cannot pay in demo mode.`,
    //   [
    //     {},
    //     {},
    //     {
    //       text: "OK",
    //       onPress: () => {
    //         console.log("OK Pressed");
    //         navigation.navigate("ticketSearch");
    //       },
    //     },
    //   ],
    //   { cancelable: false }
    // );
  };

  const paymentSuccess = async (id) => {
    try {
      const res = await captureOrder(id, accessToken);
      console.log("fimal res ", res);
      console.log("payment success!");
      clearPaypalState();
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("payment error", error);
    }
  };

  const clearPaypalState = () => {
    setPaypalUrl(null);
    setAccessToken(null);
  };

  const onWebUrlChange = (webviewState) => {
    if (webviewState?.url?.includes("https://example.com/cancel")) {
      clearPaypalState();
      return;
    }
    if (webviewState?.url?.includes("https://example.com/return")) {
      const urlValues = queryString.parseUrl(webviewState.url);
      console.log(urlValues);
      const { token } = urlValues.query;
      console.log(token);
      if (!!token) {
        paymentSuccess(token);
      }
    }
    console.log("web state url is", webviewState?.url);
  };

  return (
    <Wrapper>
      <ImageHeader>
        <TicketFinderHeader navigation={navigation} />
      </ImageHeader>
      <View style={{ margin: 20, flex: 1 }}>
        <View style={{ justifyContent: "center", alignItems: "center" }}>
          <T>Confirm Payment</T>
        </View>
        <View>
          <PaymentDetailsCard total={selectedtotal} />
        </View>
        <View
          style={{
            marginVertical: 20,
            width: "100%",
            justifyContent: "center",
            alignItems: "center",
          }}
        >
          <Button
            icon="arrow-left"
            mode="contained"
            buttonColor="#1560bd"
            style={{ width: "80%" }}
            onPress={handlePress}
          >
            <T>Proceed To Pay</T>
          </Button>
        </View>
      </View>
      <Modal visible={!!paypalUrl}>
        <Button mode="contained" onPress={clearPaypalState}>
          Close
        </Button>
        <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
          <WebView
            source={{ uri: paypalUrl }}
            onNavigationStateChange={(webviewState) =>
              onWebUrlChange(webviewState)
            }
          />
        </View>
      </Modal>
    </Wrapper>
  );
}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.